# Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool'

Tags: c#, combobox, type-conversion, operands

I would like to do a comparison of :
ComboBox.SelectedItem which is of the object type to the string.Empty in combination with "||"

If I run with above command I get an error:

> "Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and
>   'bool' "

Code

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedItem || comboBox1.SelectedItem == string.Empty )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if ((comboBox1.SelectedItem?.Equals(string.Empty) ?? false)
    || (comboBox2.SelectedItem?.Equals(string.Empty) ?? false))
```

Comment: I need to check it for all the combobox from 1 to 10 in same if statement and I need a || operator

Comment: @Parnalp so what?

Comment: I could have simply written :
string  combox1 = comboBox1.SelectedItem as string;
if(combox1 == string.Empty)
Its the same what you did.

Comment: I think you should run it before posting, I am sorry but for ?? it shows the same error

Comment: @Parnalp I run it before posting. Recheck your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if((comboBox1.SelectedItem==null || comboBox1.SelectedItem == string.Empty) || (comboBox2.SelectedItem == null || comboBox2.SelectedItem == string.Empty))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Select Item!");
}
```

Comment: Now it should be fine

Comment: nope.. throws in the same error "Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool' "

Comment: Okay wait i just try to implement i'll make you sure about it

Comment: Yeah,  now it's fine you can Judge it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare bool and object (selected item of a combo box)
based on @ThierryV answer you can define an function like this for check your condition :

```
private bool CheckEmptyComboBox(ComboBox comboBox)
{
    return (comboBox.SelectedItem==string.Empty ?? false)
}
```

and then should use this function in your if statement condition:

```
if( CheckEmptyComboBox(comboBox1) || CheckEmptyComboBox(comboBox2) || CheckEmptyComboBox(comboBox3) ...)
```

also you can use a foreach statement to find all Combo boxes in a panel or group box